# Flutter, How shadow clipping system work?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm so confused about how the clipping system in Flutter works.

---

So I will start with this example, Non of the shadow has been clipped.

Even the shadow was overflow from its self or its parent container.

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("test"),
      Container(
        margin: paddingTheme.edgeInsets,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ShadowBox(),
            ShadowBox(),
            ShadowBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

---

Now if I add more `ShadowBox()` until it overflows, All the shadow will be clipped.

For example:

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("test"),
      Container(
        margin: paddingTheme.edgeInsets,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ShadowBox(),
            ShadowBox(),
            ShadowBox(),
            ShadowBox(), // ADD THIS
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

---

Now even I change `Row` to be `SingleChildScrollView` or `List` it's still clipped, But not overflow

```
Container(
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Text("test"),
      Container(
        margin: paddingTheme.edgeInsets,
        child: ListView.builder( // CHANGE FROM ROW TO LIST
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          itemCount: 5,
          itemBuilder: (c, i) => ShadowBox(),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

---

So the question is how it's work, And how can I prevent these shadows to be clipped?

Or it's a design flaw of Flutter itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had fire this in the Flutter's issue.

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67858

As I understand from now, The default ClipBehaviour of `Container` `Row` `Column` is different from `ListView` and internal `Overflow`.

So we have a workaround by adding `clipBehaviour: Clip.none` to the ListView.

Comment: Thanks! Works with SingleChildScrollView as well.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: To get the overlap shadows and no clipping, you can try:

In `ShadowBox()` widget,

```
Container(
       height: 100,
       width: 100,
       margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20,bottom: 20), <-----
       decoration:BoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.white,
            boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.blue,blurRadius: 12)]
       ),
),
```

**As for why it is clipped?**

In Flutter engine, clipping the shadow is default behavior.

If you go deep in code you will find that shadow's width/height is not taken into account while rendering children in ListView or any widget. So you have to take care of it.

**Why is it not clipping in Row/Column then?**

In Rows and columns, no clipping is visible because it assumes the height of Row/Column as per the parent's max height/width. So it's height/width is at Max/Infinity.

So if you increase the width and height of the `ListView()`'s parent `Container()` widget, clipping will not happen as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, But this still not explained why it's clipped.
I didn't found any code inside ListView that clipped the shadow.
And if ListView clipped why overflow Row and Column also clipped.

Comment: I'm afraid this still not the solution to my problem. As you see in the image a BoxShadow's shadow overlaps with the next BoxShadow's shadow. Adding padding will prevent those.

Comment: Oh sure, I have updated the answer to get the overlap shadows and no clipping in the listview

Comment: I have also added the explanation for why is shadow clipped.

Comment: I apologize, But the answer is still a bit ambiguous, So it does not work and the answer is the default Flutter Engine itself. So I still don't know the reason behind and if this is by design or by intent.

Comment: btw, the margin using margin on the top and bottom may fix the top and the bottom. But doesn't fix the LR sides of ListView. And this solution also deforms how the ShadowBox size should be.